# How do I add a vertical break after table captions?

Tags: tables, captions, article, report

I have noticed that in LaTeX, `article` does not create vertical whitespace after a table caption. Is there a way to make this (and only this) act like it does in `report` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LaTeX inserts a vertical skip of `\belowcaptionskip` which defaults to 0pt so you can set

```
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{10pt}
```

the `caption` and `float` packages gives more extensive customisation possibilities including different spacing for tables and figures etc.